# Join-Group PySpark - SQL to Pysaprk

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to join 2 tables based on this SQL query using pyspark.

```
%sql
SELECT c.cust_id, avg(b.gender_score) AS pub_masc
FROM df  c
 LEFT JOIN pub_df b 
   ON c.pp = b.pp 
GROUP BY c.cust_id
)
```

I tried following in pyspark but I am not sure if it's the right way as I was stuck to display my data. so I just choose .max

```
df.select('cust_id', 'pp') \
                .join(pub_df, on = ['pp'], how = 'left')\
                .avg(gender_score) as pub_masc
                .groupBy('cust_id').max()
```

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your Python code contains an invalid line `.avg(gender_score) as pub_masc`. Also you should group by and then average, not the other way round.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select('cust_id', 'pp') \
  .join(pub_df, on = ['pp'], how = 'left')\
  .groupBy('cust_id')\
  .agg(F.avg('gender_score').alias('pub_masc'))
```